# Setting up codemirror 6 in ASP.Net core application

Tags: javascript, codemirror, javascript-import, codemirror-6

I'm a noob regarding codemirror v6 and working with scripts files using imports.

Im trying to get any example working from [here](https://codemirror.net/examples/decoration/)

So far i'm not getting anywhere with it. The sources are fetched with npm for example [view](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@codemirror/view);

Any help or example for setting stuff like this up is highly appreciated

I would like any kind of working starting point from which i can build

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
You can download [this code mirror repo](https://github.com/codemirror/dev) and follow the instructions in readme.md, you can get the basic version of CodeMirror working.

Option 2: Follow this [medium article](https://medium.com/datacamp-engineering/codemirror-6-getting-started-7fd08f467ed2) to get started with CodeMirror